# Using a parsec parser in the IO monad

Tags: haskell, monads, parsec, io-monad

I've defined a parser using Parsec, which has type `Parsec Text () a` for some `a`. I've also got a "deal with this chunk" function, which writes the thing I've parsed to a file and has type `a -> IO ()`. The file format that it's parsing means that we get back to "top level" reasonably frequently.

Is there a way to take my original parser and "lift it" into the IO monad? I'm imagining something with the following type signature:

```
liftParser :: Parsec Text () a -> (a -> IO ()) -> ParsecT Text () IO ()
```

where the first argument is the pure parser and the second is the "do something with the thing I parsed" function.

Obviously, I can bodge together what I need by redefining my original parser in IO too, but that means my unit tests look horrible, and it just feels like the wrong approach.

Also, I can't do something crazy like calling `runParserT` because that would drop the source position information - if there's an error on line 1000 of the input, I'd like the error message to say so.

So is there a way to do this and, if so, how? Also, is this a sensible thing to do? I imagine that I'm at least managing to avoid accumulating the output data. And, assuming that I manage something like this, should I expect `Parsec` to manage to discard the input data that it's already dealt with?

Comment: Why not define your original parser polymorphically. `ParsecT Text () m`, leaving `m` undecided.  Then your pure tests can test it on `Identity`, but you can instantiate at `IO` when you need to.

Comment: I've used luqui's approach with great results for unit testing before, and I'd definitely do it again. If you still find yourself wanting to call `runParserT` for whichever reason, you can simply use `setPosition` to set Parsec's idea of the current source location (without skipping in the stream).

Comment: luqui: Good point, that's exactly what I should be doing! Could you reply with an answer? I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Ah! Maybe that's actually a better approach for me - it will guarantee that Parsec doesn't need to hold on to any other internal state between top-levels. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this question can be marked as answered: luqui's comment above explains how to do it.

The trick is to define all your parsers polymorphically, with type `ParsecT Text () m` (the definitions all end up looking like `thing :: Monad m => Parsec Text () m MyType`). Then you can instantiate with `m` the identity monad in the test-bench and equal to `IO` where they are used.